# How to properly handle customer subscription updated event

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I've setup Stripe so that customers can manage their subscription through Stripe's customer portal.

In order to keep my app in sync with Stripe, I've created a web hook to handle `customer.subscription.updated` events. The idea is to simply get the price/plan the customer has changed to and then update a column in the Db to reflect that.

The problem however, is that when a customer makes the change via the portal. My webhook receives 2 subscription updated events. One containing a subscription object holding the old plan/price info, and the other containing a subscription with the new plan and price data.

How would I go about distinguishing which event is for the old price/plan and which is for the new so that I can ignore the old one and only update the db field using the new price/plan?

Event object for old subscription price/plan: https://pastebin.com/NA2KPh90

Event object for new subscription price/plan: https://pastebin.com/qF9g1wDs

Comment: Hard to say without actually seeing them

Comment: I've added links to the event objects that are sent to the webhook

Comment: So looking at https://www.diffchecker.com/KJuMKqdp this looks like it’s the first time it’s set? There’s lots of detail in the second one that isn’t in the first one. What you might have to do is save both of them and use the one with the higher `created` value..

Comment: Well, it would be the first time moved to a paid plan. All our customers have a subscription created on stripe during registration and this subscription is set to a free plan/price initially. In this particular case, I registered a test user and then moved from the free plan to a paid one.

Comment: But I guess I could take a look at the previous items compared to the current items and try to see which update event is the correct one from that since the latest one should have the user's current plan in the previous items and the new one in the current items, where as the incorrect event would have the old plan in the current items. Seems kinda weird though, as if there should be an easier way to tell.

Comment: In the event payload, you can look at `previous_attributes` to see the attributes that actually changed.  So if you see a `price` in the `previous_attributes`, it means the price of the subscription changed.